# Add arrows to stock graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, ipython

I am using the following code to display stock data:

```
from pandas.io.data import get_data_yahoo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = get_data_yahoo("ADS", start = '2012-01-01', end = '2012-12-31')[['Close','Volume']] 
data.plot(subplots = True, figsize = (8, 8)); 
plt.title('Adidas-Aktie 2012')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

At certain date positions, I would like to add arrows pointing directly to the graph.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Gigi Hofleitner.

Comment: [check annotating text in Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I checked that before, but do not know exactly, how to access the subplot. Again, i am a beginner...:-)

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'annotate' is the error I get when trying to define the plot as ax1 and use ax1.annnotate. I think it must be somehow related to the representation of above pandas data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 from pandas.io.data import get_data_yahoo
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 data = get_data_yahoo("ADS", start = '2012-01-01', end = '2012-12-31' [['Close','Volume']] 
 ax = data.plot(subplots = True, figsize = (8, 8)); 
 plt.title('Adidas-Aktie 2012')
 plt.legend(loc = 'best')
 ax[0].annotate('your text',xy =(locx,locy), xytext=(locx,locy), arrowprops = dict(facecolor = 'black')) # assuming the you want to annotate the first plot
 plt.show()
```

In the code above, (locx,locy) is the location of the text where you want your annotation

Comment: I tried the same in parallel and it worked, Many Thanks for your help! My issue was that I did not know, how to access each subplot data.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pandas.io.data import get_data_yahoo
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = get_data_yahoo("ADS", start = '2007-01-01', end = '2013-10-01')[['Close', 'Volume']] 
ax1=data.plot(subplots = True,figsize = (8, 8)); 
ax1[0].annotate("test",xy=(datetime(2012,03,01),130),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red'))
plt.title('Adidas-Aktie 2012')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()